# gnokii cannot send sms

Tags: sms

the following gnokii command fails:

```
echo "this is a test message" | sudo gnokii --phone ATblue --sendsms +<number> -r
```

i can recieve sms and get network info using the current config file.
the above command results in this:

```
GNOKII Version 0.6.28
*** glibc detected *** gnokii: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09a7b540 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0x4ed591]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0x4eede8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x4f1ecd]
/usr/lib/libgnokii.so.5(gn_char_def_alphabet+0xb3)[0x3d2a43]
gnokii[0x805bb78]
gnokii[0x804b948]
gnokii[0x804b230]
gnokii[0x804bd5f]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6)[0x498bd6]
gnokii[0x804ab61]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00116000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 315119     /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
00116000-00117000 r--p 00005000 08:01 315119     /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
00117000-00119000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 315119     /lib/libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
00119000-0011b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 260201     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl-2.11.1.so
0011b000-0011c000 r--p 00001000 08:01 260201     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl-2.11.1.so
0011c000-0011d000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 260201     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl-2.11.1.so
0011d000-00132000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 260266     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00132000-00133000 r--p 00014000 08:01 260266     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00133000-00134000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 260266     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.1.so
00134000-00136000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00136000-0014e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268696     /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
0014e000-0014f000 r--p 00017000 08:01 268696     /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
0014f000-00150000 rw-p 00018000 08:01 268696     /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1.1.0
00150000-00152000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267689     /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
00152000-00153000 r--p 00001000 08:01 267689     /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
00153000-00154000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 267689     /usr/lib/libXau.so.6.0.0
00154000-00158000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267700     /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
00158000-00159000 r--p 00003000 08:01 267700     /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
00159000-0015a000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 267700     /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
0020a000-0024c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 268247     /usr/lib/libical.so.0.44.0
0024c000-00254000 r--p 00042000 08:01 268247     /usr/lib/libical.so.0.44.0
00254000-00255000 rw-p 0004a000 08:01 268247     /usr/lib/libical.so.0.44.0
00340000-0035d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 260186     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0035d000-0035e000 r--p 0001c000 08:01 260186     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0035e000-0035f000 rw-p 0001d000 08:01 260186     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
003a9000-00431000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 302338     /usr/lib/libgnokii.so.5.0.0
00431000-00432000 ---p 00088000 08:01 302338     /usr/lib/libgnokii.so.5.0.0
00432000-00435000 r--p 00088000 08:01 302338     /usr/lib/libgnokii.so.5.0.0
00435000-00437000 rw-p 0008b000 08:01 302338     /usr/lib/libgnokii.so.5.0.0
00437000-0047c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00481000-00482000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00482000-005d5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 260156     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005d5000-005d6000 ---p 00153000 08:01 260156     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005d6000-005d8000 r--p 00153000 08:01 260156     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005d8000-005d9000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 260156     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005d9000-005dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
006ca000-006d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 260246     /lib/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
006d3000-006d4000 r--p 00009000 08:01 260246     /lib/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
006d4000-006d5000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 260246     /lib/libpcsclite.so.1.0.0
007f6000-00809000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267800     /usr/lib/libbluetooth.so.3.5.0
00809000-0080a000 r--p 00012000 08:01 267800     /usr/lib/libbluetooth.so.3.5.0
0080a000-0080b000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 267800     /usr/lib/libbluetooth.so.3.5.0
008b5000-009ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267685     /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
009ce000-009cf000 r--p 00118000 08:01 267685     /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
009cf000-009d1000 rw-p 00119000 08:01 267685     /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0
009d1000-009d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00dc3000-00dd2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 267720     /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4.11.0
00dd2000-00dd3000 r--p 0000e000 08:01 267720     /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4.11.0
00dd3000-00dd4000 rw-p 0000f000 08:01 267720     /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4.11.0
00fcd000-00fe8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 264975     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00fe8000-00fe9000 r--p 0001a000 08:01 264975     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
00fe9000-00fea000 rw-p 0001b000 08:01 264975     /lib/ld-2.11.1.so
08048000-08067000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 302405     /usr/bin/gnokii
08067000-08068000 r--p 0001e000 08:01 302405     /usr/bin/gnokii
08068000-08069000 rw-p 0001f000 08:01 302405     /usr/bin/gnokii
08069000-0806c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
09a79000-09add000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7500000-b7521000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7521000-b7600000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7662000-b7669000 r--s 00000000 08:01 280697     /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b76a9000-b76ed000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76ed000-b772c000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272703     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_CTYPE
b772c000-b784a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272702     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_COLLATE
b784a000-b784e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7860000-b7861000 r--p 00000000 08:01 266931     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_NUMERIC
b7861000-b7862000 r--p 00000000 08:01 266932     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_TIME
b7862000-b7863000 r--p 00000000 08:01 266933     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MONETARY
b7863000-b7864000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272751     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
b7864000-b7865000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272709     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_PAPER
b7865000-b7866000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272668     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_NAME
b7866000-b7867000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272493     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_ADDRESS
b7867000-b7868000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272502     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_TELEPHONE
b7868000-b7869000 r--p 00000000 08:01 272705     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_MEASUREMENT
b7869000-b786a000 r--p 00000000 08:01 266934     /usr/lib/locale/en_IN/LC_IDENTIFICATION
b786a000-b786c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfcec000-bfd6f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted
```

Comment: sorry for the garbage. (it looked good in the edit box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in gnokii 0.6.29